# Change object value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in my jQuery. Can someone help me fix it? I have my code on jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tbk5tuj9/

My problem is, I want to change `image source_image_width` and `height` to other size. Is it possible on my code?

This is my jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var value = {};

    value = {
        "zoom_element": '#zoom',
        "magnifier_opacity": 1,
        "source_image_width": 200,
        "source_image_height": 200,
    };

    $(".klik").click(function () {
        console.log("Klik");
        value = {
            zoom_element: '#zoom',
            magnifier_opacity: 1,
            source_image_width: 2,
            source_image_height: 100,
        };
    });

    $('#etalage').etalage(value);

    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: **Possibly** a duplicate of [*How to return the response from an asynchronous call?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), but I'll leave it to others to make the call (if I voted, Mjolnir would kick in).

Comment: I understand, you want that: http://jsfiddle.net/tbk5tuj9/9/  ???

Comment: thanks for comment A.Wolff , but when i click "klik", it make some picture again sir @A.Wolff

Answer (score 1):

Your code is completely replacing the `value` object, successfully. The only (real) issue is that your `console.log` is **outside** your `click` handler. If you want to see `value` as it is after clicking it, you need to move that *into* your click handler.

---

Lesser issues are that you're creating an object here:

```
var value = {};
```

...that you then throw away entirely and replace here:

```
value = {
    "zoom_element": '#zoom',
        "magnifier_opacity": 1,
        "source_image_width": 200,
        "source_image_height": 200,
};
```

Those could be combined, or just leave the `= {}` off the `var` line.

---

Also, if you just want to *modify* your object, you can just assign to its properties, e.g.:

```
value.magnifier_opacity = 1;
```

---

Example that just moves the `console.log` but still replaces the entire object:

```js
$(function() {
  var value = {};

  value = {
    "zoom_element": '#zoom',
    "magnifier_opacity": 1,
    "source_image_width": 200,
    "source_image_height": 200,
  };

  $(".klik").click(function() {
    snippet.log("Klik");
    value = {
      zoom_element: '#zoom',
      magnifier_opacity: 1,
      source_image_width: 2,
      source_image_height: 100,
    };
    snippet.log(JSON.stringify(value)); // <========= Moved and
                                        // adjusted for demo
  });

  // $('#etalage').etalage(value); Commented out for demo
});
```

```html
<input type="button" class="klik" value="Click me">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and solution sir. i try it but still no changes at my source image width and height. my problem is when i click, it changes source image width and height and reload $('#etalage') with new object